# Compilation failure "configure: error: udev support requested but libudev header not installed"

Tags: libusb, usbserial

I did following on my ubuntu machine:

1. Git clone https://github.com/libusb/libusb.git
2. after extraction, ran ./autogen.sh script, this failed with following error:

> checking libudev.h usability... no  checking libudev.h presence... no 
>   checking for libudev.h... no  configure: error: udev support requested
>   but libudev header not installed

I also tried installing `libudev` using following command `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` but it fails with following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libudev1 udev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libudev-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libudev1 udev
2 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,197 kB of archives.
After this operation, 539 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 229-4ubuntu17
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 229-4ubuntu17
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libudev-dev amd64 229-4ubuntu17
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_229-4ubuntu17_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev1_229-4ubuntu17_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev-dev_229-4ubuntu17_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Aborting install.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this to working. First i installed `libudev-dev` the hardway.

1.`wget http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev-dev_204-5ubuntu20_amd64.deb` and `wget http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev1_204-5ubuntu20_amd64.deb`

2. Installed these packages using `sudo dpkg -i <*.deb>`
3. Now, ran `./autogen.sh` under libusb folder.

Configuration completed successfully!

Answer (score 7):

`sudo apt install libudev-dev` works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Better to switch to Fedora, I spent a lot of time with crashes and asserts after this. libudev in Fedora is more stable (Fedora 33)